# react: fetch data from rest api according to id

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

i want to fetch a single post from a lis of posts, i already set up  individual links for each post in the api
views.py

```
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def Post_detail(request,pk):
        try: 
            post_detail = Post.objects.get(pk=pk) 
        except post_detail.DoesNotExist: 
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'The Post does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        Post_serializer = PostSerializer(post_detail) 
        return JsonResponse({'data': Post_serializer.data})
```

i don't know how to actually fetch it on react, how do i get the id?

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/Post' + id);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            post: data,
            loading: false
        });
        
    }
```

i am also open to using axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, `id` is added as part of URL `www.test.com/post/id`
In React with `react-router-dom`

`import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';`

`<Route exact path="/post/:id" component={Article} />`

Then you can get parameter on your page where u have to fetch data with id

`const {id} = useParams();`
and do
`const response = await fetch('/api/Post/' + id);`

Btw i recommend you to use React hooks

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct, you will need to put a `/` after `/api/Post`, so that the endpoint is correct.

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/Post/' + id);
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({
    post: data,
    loading: false
  });
}
```

With axios, it would look something like this (you could also use `async/await` if you like):

```js
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('/api/Post/' + id).then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      post: response.data,
      loading: false
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  })
}
```